# WSO2 Message Broker, This node is not the slot coordinator right now

Tags: wso2, cluster-computing, message, broker

I want to cluster my WSO2 Message Broker 3.1.0 in two nodes.
I configured those two nodes by changing the repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file:

```
<parameter name="localMemberHost">10.0.0.43</parameter>

<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
 <clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
            enable="true">


 <members>
        <member>
            <hostName>10.0.0.45</hostName>
            <port>4000</port>
        </member>
    </members>
```

the first node work without problem, but when i launch the second node, i get the message :

```
ERROR {org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction} -  Internal error processing updateCurrentMessageIdForSafeZone org.apache.thrift.TException: This node is not the slot coordinator right now
    at org.wso2.andes.thrift.SlotManagementServiceImpl.updateCurrentMessageIdForSafeZone(SlotManagementServiceImpl.java:110)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have followed up below steps.

- Update IP address in repository/conf/broker.xml

MB1

```
<!-- Thrift is used to maintain and sync slot (message groups) ranges between MB nodes. -->
        <thriftServerHost>10.0.0.43</thriftServerHost>
```

MB2

```
<!-- Thrift is used to maintain and sync slot (message groups) ranges between MB nodes. -->
        <thriftServerHost>10.0.0.45</thriftServerHost>
```

- Update below hazelcast properties in both nodes. repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

MB1

```
 <clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
 <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>

<parameter name="localMemberHost">10.0.0.43</parameter>

<members>
            <member>
                <hostName>10.0.0.45</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
        </members>
```

MB2

```
 <clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
 <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>

<parameter name="localMemberHost">10.0.0.45</parameter>

<members>
            <member>
                <hostName>10.0.0.43</hostName>
                <port>4000</port>
            </member>
        </members>
```

Hope this would help you.